# How to use Multi WhereNotIn in fireStore with Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I need to use multi WhereNotIn as conditions in fireStore.

But fireStore only supplies single WhereNotIn.

How to make it possible with multi condition?

```
  var storeBuilder: Query?

                userDB.document("$userId")
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                        var blockedUser =
                            document.data?.getValue("blockedUser") as ArrayList<*>
                        var blockedDiary =
                            document.data?.getValue("blockedDiary") as ArrayList<*>

                        if (blockedUser.isNotEmpty() && blockedDiary.isNotEmpty()) {
                            storeBuilder = diaryDB
                                .whereNotIn("diaryId", blockedDiary)
                                .whereNotIn("userId", blockedUser)
                        } else if (blockedUser.isNotEmpty() && blockedDiary.isEmpty()) {
                            storeBuilder = diaryDB
                                .whereNotIn("userId", blockedUser)
                        } else if (blockedUser.isEmpty() && blockedDiary.isNotEmpty()) {
                            storeBuilder = diaryDB
                                .whereNotIn("diaryId", blockedDiary)
                        } else {
                            storeBuilder = diaryDB
                        }
```

This line is problem among above:

```
       storeBuilder = diaryDB
                            .whereNotIn("diaryId", blockedDiary)
                            .whereNotIn("userId", blockedUser)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in), you can you at most one `in`, `not-in` or `array-contains-any` per query. The multiple `in` case may be solved by running multiple query but that's not the case with `not-in` as one query may return results that were not included by other.

The best workaround would be to use a service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/how-to/filter-by-string/#applying-a-string-filter) that supports such queries and facet filters. 
 Also checkout [Firestore Algolia Extension](https://www.algolia.com/developers/firebase-search-extension/) that might be useful in syncing the data.